# Default Value - Radio Button

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a simple radio button that specifies the type of position:

```
<div class="lead">Position</div>
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"> 
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!Job__c.Type_of_Position__c}" layout="lineDirection">
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Mentor" itemlabel="Mentor"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Consultant" itemlabel="Consultant"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="Permanent" itemlabel="Permanent"/>
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Any idea how I can set the default value to Mentor?

I tried setting a variable in the controller:

```
// Setting Default Options  
   public String posType = 'Mentor';

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Mentor','Mentor'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Consultant','Consultant'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Permanent','Permanent')); return options;
    }

    public String getPosType() {
    return posType;
        }

    public void setPosType (String posType) { 

        this.posType = posType; }
```

And the VF

```
 <div class="lead">Position</div>
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1"> 
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!posType}" layout="lineDirection">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

But no value is added when the form is submitted.  How can I return the value selected?

Comment: Change `public String posType = 'Mentor';` to `String posType = 'Mentor';`.Guess this should work

Comment: It didn't work, still no value.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the `posType` with getter/setter and set the default value in your constructor, the rest is correct:

```
public String posType { get; set; }

public YourClass(){
    posType = 'Consultant';
}

public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Mentor','Mentor'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Consultant','Consultant'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Permanent','Permanent')); 
    return options;
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!posType}" layout="lineDirection">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

The code above works on my dev org.

Comment: It passes the value, but doesn't display the default value to the client on the frontend.

Comment: @gatonegro The code above works for me. Check the `selectRadio` structure.

Comment: It defaults on the front end to have the consultant selected?